# Moq mock method with out specifying input parameter

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

I have some code in a test using Moq:

```
public class Invoice
{
    ...

    public bool IsInFinancialYear(FinancialYearLookup financialYearLookup)
    {
        return InvoiceDate >= financialYearLookup.StartDate && InvoiceDate <= financialYearLookup.EndDate;
    }
    ...
}
```

So in a unit test I'm trying to mock this method and make it return true

```
mockInvoice.Setup(x => x.IsInFinancialYear()).Returns(true);
```

Is there anyway to write this line so I don't have to specify the input to `IsInFinancialYear`. ie. So that it doesn't in the code what the input parameter is it will return true whatever is passed to it?

Answer (score 284, accepted):

You can use `It.IsAny<T>()` to match any value:

```
mockInvoice.Setup(x => x.IsInFinancialYear(It.IsAny<FinancialYearLookup>())).Returns(true);
```

See the [Matching Arguments](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#matching-arguments) section of the quick start.

Comment: I realize this answer is old but what if I have more than one simple parameter? Is it possible to just say "Anything where the types fit for all parameters"?

Comment: @Brandon Then you have an It.IsAny<type>() for each parameter where type is whatever type that param is. If you wanted you could probably write a helper function that does this for you via reflection.

Comment: https://7pass.wordpress.com/2014/05/20/moq-setup-and-ignore-all-arguments/

Comment: Agree with the other comments here: typing this for any non-trivial method is a major pain.

Comment: Any one does have any helper that do this ? Or you have to write for each single method a helper /

Answer (score 20):

Try using `It.IsAny<FinancialYearLookup>()` to accept any argument:

```
mockInvoice.Setup(x => x.IsInFinancialYear(It.IsAny<FinancialYearLookup>())).Returns(true);
```

Answer (score 14):

You can try the following:

https://7pass.wordpress.com/2014/05/20/moq-setup-and-ignore-all-arguments/

Allows:

```
mock
.SetupIgnoreArgs(x => x.Method(null, null, null)
.Return(value);
```

Comment: Pull Request to Moq Extensions would be appreciated :-)

Comment: TWIMC, copy of the gist on Internet Archive - https://web.archive.org/web/20170914105329/https://gist.github.com/7Pass/1c6b329e85ca29071f42